# My script has no effects in more than 3 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

The script works fine when it has 2 rows. Stop reading from 3.

This is MSSQL Server 2005. Try anyway without any result.

```
DECLARE @CurrentAccountLevel int
DECLARE @CurrentAccountExpireDate smalldatetime

SELECT @CurrentAccountLevel=Type,@CurrentAccountExpireDate=Date FROM T_VIPList

IF(@CurrentAccountLevel <> 0 AND getdate() > @CurrentAccountExpireDate)
BEGIN
SET @CurrentAccountLevel = '0'

UPDATE T_VIPList SET Type=@CurrentAccountLevel,Date=@CurrentAccountExpireDate 
END
```

There is no error message. But if I have more than 10 rows, it doesn't affect the row that should affect.

Comment: Your script has a MAJOR flaw. You have a scalar variable being set from a select statement that and T_VIPList might contain more than 1 row. As a result the variables will be set to an arbitrary value from that table/view. The behavior you are experiencing is because of the logical flaw here, not the number of rows.

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to do here. Please post a sample data and the expected results as formatted text

Comment: And it is long past due for you to upgrade your database. Sql server 2005 has been out of support since 2016. The 2008 version is not even supported anymore.

Comment: @SeanLange That is what I want. It is a VIP membership. When you reach a certain date you should change the Type status from 1 to 0. That's why there is no WHERE.

Comment: @Sami
Basically I want the Type to change from 1 to 0 when it reaches a certain date. Respond to a VIP membership

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the new information in your comment you should simplify this to an update statement. There is no need for variables, IF statements etc.

```
UPDATE T_VIPList SET Type = '0'
where Date < getdate()
    and Type <> '0'
```